# Set Product Image Position

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create one dropdown product attribute for the set products image position like "top-right", "top-left", "bottom-left", "bottom-right".

Comment: Have you already created an attribute and added it to the product attribute set?

Comment: no till now i did not create attribute

Comment: Then create it, type "drop-down" with the options you need.

Comment: need to create custom attribute for that?